# optimize iteration over a list of sorted periods

Tags: go

given a list of periods, already sorted, and containing no dups.

```golang
periods := periods{
    period{min: 0, max: time.Millisecond},
    period{min: time.Millisecond, max: time.Millisecond * 1},
    period{min: time.Millisecond * 1, max: time.Millisecond * 2},
    period{min: time.Millisecond * 2, max: time.Millisecond * 7},
    period{min: time.Millisecond * 7, max: 0},
}
```

with the types `periods` and `period` defined as

```golang
type periods []period

func (ks periods) index(v time.Duration) period {
    for i := 0; i < len(ks); i++ {
        if ks[i].contains(v) {
            return ks[i]
        }
    }
    return period{}
}

type period struct {
    min time.Duration
    max time.Duration
}

func (k period) String() string {
    if k.max == 0 && k.max < k.min {
        return fmt.Sprintf("%v-", k.min)
    }
    return fmt.Sprintf("%v-%v", k.min, k.max)
}

func (k period) contains(t time.Duration) bool {
    if t <= 0 && k.min == 0 {
        return true
    }
    return t > k.min && (k.max == 0 || t <= k.max)
}
```

The full code is available at https://play.golang.org/p/cDmQ7Ho6hUI

Can you suggest solution(s) to improve the search implementation in the `periods.index` function ?

Also, can you provide a factorized solution such as it is possible to re use the implementation ?
A generics included solution is OK for that i can still specialize using code gen.

A benchmark is included

```golang
func BenchmarkIndex(b *testing.B) {
    periods := periods{
        period{min: 0, max: 8000},
        period{min: 8000, max: 16000},
        period{min: 16000, max: 24000},
        period{min: 24000, max: 32000},
        period{min: 32000, max: 40000},
        period{min: 40000, max: 48000},
        period{min: 48000, max: 56000},
        period{min: 56000, max: 64000},
        period{min: 64000, max: 72000},
        period{min: 72000, max: 80000},
        period{min: 80000, max: 0},
    }

    inputs := []time.Duration{
        time.Duration(0),
        time.Duration(72000 + 1),
        time.Duration(80000 + 1),
    }
    b.ResetTimer()
    b.ReportAllocs()
    for i := 0; i < b.N; i++ {
        for _, input := range inputs {
            _ = periods.index(input)
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's unlikely you can achieve better performance than a simple, sequential search for a list as small as yours (11 elements).

If your slice would be much bigger (e.g. hundreds or even thousands of periods), since your `periods` is sorted as you claim,  then you could use binary search.

Binary search is implemented in [`sort.Search()`](https://pkg.go.dev/sort#Search). You just basically have to provide a `lessOrContains()` implementation for `period`. This is how it could look like:

```
func (k period) lessOrContains(t time.Duration) bool {
    return k.max == 0 || t <= k.max
}
```

Now an `index()` function using binary search:

```
func (ks periods) indexBinary(v time.Duration) period {
    idx := sort.Search(len(ks), func(i int) bool {
        return ks[i].lessOrContains(v)
    })
    if idx < len(ks) && ks[idx].contains(v) {
        return ks[idx]
    }
    return period{}
}
```

Now on to benchmarking. Let's create a `createPeriods()` helper function that creates either a small or big periods slice:

```
func createPeriods(big bool) periods {
    ps := periods{
        period{min: 0, max: 8000},
        period{min: 8000, max: 16000},
        period{min: 16000, max: 24000},
        period{min: 24000, max: 32000},
        period{min: 32000, max: 40000},
        period{min: 40000, max: 48000},
        period{min: 48000, max: 56000},
        period{min: 56000, max: 64000},
        period{min: 64000, max: 72000},
        period{min: 72000, max: 80000},
        period{min: 80000, max: 0},
    }

    if big {
        psbig := periods{}
        for i := 0; i < 1000; i++ {
            psbig = append(psbig, period{time.Duration(i), time.Duration(i + 1)})
        }
        psbig = append(psbig, ps[1:]...)
        ps = psbig
    }

    return ps
}
```

Now let's write benchmark functions for all cases:

```
func BenchmarkIndexSmall(b *testing.B) {
    benchmarkIndexImpl(b, false)
}

func BenchmarkIndexBinarySmall(b *testing.B) {
    benchmarkIndexBinaryImpl(b, false)
}

func BenchmarkIndexBig(b *testing.B) {
    benchmarkIndexImpl(b, true)
}

func BenchmarkIndexBinaryBig(b *testing.B) {
    benchmarkIndexBinaryImpl(b, true)
}

func benchmarkIndexImpl(b *testing.B, big bool) {
    periods := createPeriods(big)

    inputs := []time.Duration{
        time.Duration(0),
        time.Duration(72000 + 1),
        time.Duration(80000 + 1),
    }
    b.ResetTimer()
    b.ReportAllocs()
    for i := 0; i < b.N; i++ {
        for _, input := range inputs {
            _ = periods.index(input)
        }
    }
}

func benchmarkIndexBinaryImpl(b *testing.B, big bool) {
    periods := createPeriods(big)

    inputs := []time.Duration{
        time.Duration(0),
        time.Duration(72000 + 1),
        time.Duration(80000 + 1),
    }
    b.ResetTimer()
    b.ReportAllocs()
    for i := 0; i < b.N; i++ {
        for _, input := range inputs {
            _ = periods.indexBinary(input)
        }
    }
}
```

And now let's see the benchmark results:

```
BenchmarkIndexSmall-8        44408948      25.50 ns/op    0 B/op     0 allocs/op
BenchmarkIndexBinarySmall-8  18441049      58.35 ns/op    0 B/op     0 allocs/op
BenchmarkIndexBig-8            562202    1908 ns/op       0 B/op     0 allocs/op
BenchmarkIndexBinaryBig-8     9234846     125.1 ns/op     0 B/op     0 allocs/op
```

As you can see, `index()` is faster than `indexBinary()` for small lists with 11 elements (25 ns vs 58 ns).

But when the list gets big (more than a thousand periods, 1010 in the above benchmark), then `indexBinary()` outperforms `index()` by more than an order of magnitude (125 ns vs 2000 ns), and this difference will get even bigger if the lists gets bigger.

Comment: awesome. This is so great this is already provided by the standard library, i was not aware, and did implement a version too. It is very cool how you made sense of the benchmarks too. Using a custom implementation i faced somewhat unexpected results too, thats why my tests values were biased toward worst case. Though that was the idea.

Comment: So an efficient solution requires to implement both, then have a switch to decide which implementation to use at runtime, depending on arbitrary input length.

Comment: @mh-cbon Yes, if you want best performance for all input lists, you could have a check, and call either `index()` or `indexBinary()`. You have to test at what size is the turning point.

Comment: @mh-cbon Although do note that when the lists are small, even the binary search completes well below 0.1 µs. You have to decide whether the increased complexity is worth it.

Comment: for somewhat reasons, i noticed that adding a check upon limits of the list improves performance. but i can not say if i am not victim of a side effect regarding the shape of the data. like in https://play.golang.org/p/L8mJ1LQp5l3

Comment: the full test that bugs me https://play.golang.org/p/C0whleE1rtU

Comment: @mh-cbon What's the problem with it?

Comment: `indexStdWithChecks` is twice faster than `indexStd`, the only difference if that it check for elements at index `0` and `len(n)-1`. I dont understand why, though, i also figured that there must be a good reason that those two checks are not already in the standard algorithm https://cs.opensource.google/go/go/+/refs/tags/go1.17:src/sort/search.go;l=59.

Comment: @mh-cbon The explanation is rather simple. You explicite check if the first or last periods are the ones you look for, and you test for the first and last values. Obviously they will be found first and returned, without checking any other values. Think of this example: what if you would check _first_ if the 684. element is the one you're looking for? And you write tests checking the 684. element. Obviously it would be found first. The `sort.Search()` is a general binary search algorithm, it provides best time (log(n)) time for searching any value in the slice.

Comment: Adding these extra checks only makes the `index()` functions faster if you (frequently) want to find the elements you check explicitly. If someone would never want to search for those elements, then those checks would actually make the `index()` functions slower.

Comment: `If your slice would be much bigger (e.g. hundreds or even thousands of periods), since your periods is sorted as you claim, then you could use binary search.` In the likely case it is not, do you think it would be preferable to consider a whole different solution such as building a binary tree and querying over it ?

Comment: @mh-cbon To be sure, try it and measure (benchmark). But repeating myself from the first line of the answer: _"It's unlikely you can achieve better performance"_. Looping over 10 or 20 elements: that's like nothing. Building and navigating a tree (pointer indirections), that's already an overhead compared to a simple slice. And if the list is bigger and the tree would be profitable: then there's the more efficient binary search.